# Can we check unreal blue script code in code editor?

Tags: blueprint, unreal-engine4

I just start to learn things about Unreal4, and when I check "Blue print tutorials" I realize that blue print is a kind of combination of unreal script and kismet, only it's visualized. But all the logic and behavior seem to be as same as unreal script, so I'm wondering is there anyway we can use code editor like VS or sublime text to open the blue print source file to code it in a traditional way because as a programmer it's much more faster if we code it directly rather than drag it all over the screen. I bet epic have sort of mid-language behind blue print and translated to visual graphics in the run-time.

If we can't, I can understand all the mid-language codes are generated and followed a strict coding convention. It will be a chaos, if it's open for every one to code it directly.

Comment: I also post the question on unreal forum, and someone said:"No, bluepeint indeed is build on top of unrealscript remains, but is not compiled to any readable code but to binery. Theres community project for C# support which let you convert blueprint to C# but current target is december"

Answer (score 0):

As I have been learning Unreal4 recently (since March 2016), I have found that I am going to code my logic in C++ and then use the Blueprints for the visual interactions.

Epic does not intend for you to step in between the engine and the Blueprints.  I imagine you can if you step in the engine source code yourself, but you are not getting any assistance from Epic to do this and in all my digging to learn how to use this engine, I have not come across efforts to make this possible.  The purpose of the Blueprints is for folks without a traditional programming background to help them get started.

I agree with you, programming in Blueprints is a mess to me.  Assigning variables and if-then statements are way too much of a mess in Blueprints.